# My application getting crashes even though there is no error while building the app

Tags: java, android

In button save my application is getting crashed.
Please help me out with this issue.

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_info);

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                member.setUserName(name1.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setFirstName(name2.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setLastName(name3.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setEmail(name4.getText().toString().trim());
                ref.push().setValue("member");
                Toast.makeText(LoginInfo.this,"data Inserted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Log Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.firebasesign, PID: 20460
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebasesign/com.example.firebasesign.LoginInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.firebasesign.LoginInfo.onCreate(LoginInfo.java:34)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: see @Rohan, normally you post the error log

Comment: Please post the stack trace (crash log)

Comment: Error logs, please...

Comment: @notTdar I had posted it

Comment: You forgot to assign `btnSave` before calling `setOnClickListener()` on it. That is, you forgot `btnSave = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your log the `btnSave` object is null. You will need to get a reference to the object by calling findViewById prior to attempting to setOnClickListener()

```
 btnSave = findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId)
```

Where yourButtonId is the id that you set on the xml item

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/yourButtonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If you are using Butter Knife don't forget to add

```
  ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

to your onCreate() method